# Magento 2.3 Cloud Enterprise - Not able to upload any picture/image at all (error messages)

Tags: product-images, image-upload, media-images, directory, category-image

I'm very new to Magento and I have a functional background. I have read and followed all Magento commerce functional manuals on how to configure the Backend (creating products, customers, adding content, etc ..).

Although the functional manuals are quite easy to understand and to follow, I'm getting errors when trying to upload any image (for the product, category, content, etc ...). see screenshots of error messages encountered below.

I have read on some forums that this could be linked to the permissions of directories & files (770 & 660) or could also be linked to storage capacity (I haven't been able to create/store any product or image so doubting this could be the reason ..)

Could someone explain me what are the possible root causes, how I can check them (from a functional perspective) and how I can fix them (I have very limited technical knowledge but I can, of course, follow a step by step explanation)?

Thank you very much!

---

Not able to upload a category image via the “Upload button”, I’m getting the following error message:
[image]

It is also not possible to add a category image with the “select from the gallery” see below:
Not able to add an image via “select file” in the media gallery, I’m getting the following error message:
[image]

Not able to create a new sub-folder in the media gallery, I’m getting the following error message:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

The error you are getting suggest you to increase your server space. There is no more server space available to upload and save new images on your store.

Kindly contact to your respective hosting service provider and get increase the server space. Once they increase you should be able to upload new category images.

Let me know if you have any further queries.

Happy to help.

Thanks,